# Positive measure set after projection

Tags: lebesgue-measure, linear-transformations

Let ${\cal X} \subset {\mathbb R}^n$ be a compact set with $\mu_n({\cal X}) > 0$, where $\mu_n(\cdot)$ refers to $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure. Let ${\cal Y} \subset {\mathbb R}^d$ be
\begin{equation}
{\cal Y} = \{y\colon y = I_{d\times n}x\},
\end{equation}
where $I_{d\times n} = [I_d~0]$, and $I_d$ is a $d$-dimensional identity matrix. To be more specific, the relationship between $x$ and $y$ is that: if $x = (x_1,\ldots,x_d,\ldots,x_n)^T$, then $y = (x_1,\ldots,x_d)^T$.

Then, does $\mu_d({\cal Y}) > 0$ hold?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does hold. Otherwise, we would have
$$
X \subset Y\times \Bbb{R}^{n-d},
$$
where the right-hand side is easily seen to be a Lebesgue null-set (since $Y $ is). But this contradicts $\mu (X)>0$.

Comment: Thanks PhoemueX, and the answer is perfect! If it is convenient, could you recommend me some references about this conclusion or the related topics :-) I think I would cite them in my paper :-)

Comment: I am an engineering phd student, so the paper might be easy from your point of view :-)